# Implementing sync from mobile app to server in .net

Tags: android, .net, ios, cordova, synchronization

I'm planning a mobile app, to be built using [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/), that will sync user data with a server. The data can be edited on the app or via a web interface on the server, and some users will have multiple devices so need to sync to them all.

Anyone know of good guidelines/tutorials/patterns for this sort of thing? I can hand-code it all but I'm sure I'll make lots of common mistakes and it'd be better to either use a library or follow some good rules.

If I was doing the server in java then something like [OpenMobster](http://code.google.com/p/openmobster/) sounds good.

Answer (score 1):

have you checked out the [Sync Framework Toolkit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/silverlight/Sync-Framework-Toolkit-4dc10f0e)?

Answer (score 1):

I am looking to do the same thing and have found https://github.com/orbitaloop/WebSqlSync/.  I have not used it in anger yet, but it looks good.

Answer (score 1):

Just so that there is no stone left unturned in your research.

To use OpenMobster your server does not have to be in Java. It helps if it is, but you can have your server in any language or platform. All you have to do is expose your data via a secure REST API.

You then write the OpenMobster Sync Channel that accesses data via this REST interface. Yes, this Sync Channel has to be written in Java as it plugs into the core Sync Engine.

So architecturally speaking, you would have the OpenMobster server between your server and the mobile device.

This is the same architecture when mobilizing legacy databases, CRM systems, ERP servers, SalesForce.com, etc

Full Disclosure: I am the Chief Engineer of OpenMobster project

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll look into OpenMobster a bit more in that case